# How to merge two data sets by IDs based on another variable in R

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge two data sets with ID. Data2 is a subset of the larger data set (data1) and it was created by removing Ids which were tagged 1 in data1. In the sample data, the two data sets have the same Ids until ID 426. With ID 427 when the tag is 1 in the first data, the second data removes that entry and continues with sequential ID. Thus Id 427 in the second data is 428 in the first. Likewise ID 1865 in the second data is 1867 in the first. How could I merge this data sets? I have provided a single sample data on-line. The first data has variables id, date and tag while the second has id1 and date1

```
> dput(data1)
structure(list(id = c(426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 432L, 
1865L, 1866L, 1867L, 1868L, 1869L, 1870L, 1871L, 2388L, 2389L, 
2390L, 2391L, 2965L, 2966L, 2967L, 2968L, 2969L, 2970L), date = structure(c(11250, 
7308, 12436, 9919, 13372, 9526, 8232, 7306, 9872, 7398, 10332, 
12967, 14288, 14053, 7311, 10268, 7772, 14477, 7309, 10228, 8917, 
10216, 10873, 8065), class = "Date"), tag = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), datalabel = "", time.stamp = "24 Jan 2015 22:01", .Names = c("id", 
"date", "tag"), formats = c("%8.0g", "%tdDD_mon_CCYY", "%8.0g"
), types = c(252L, 254L, 251L), val.labels = c("", "", ""), var.labels = c("", 
"", ""), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24"), version = 12L, class = "data.frame")
> 



> dput(data2)
structure(list(id1 = c(426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 432L, 
1865L, 1866L, 1867L, 1868L, 1869L, 1870L, 1871L, 2388L, 2389L, 
2390L, 2391L, 2965L, 2966L, 2967L, 2968L, 2969L, 2970L), date1 = structure(c(11250, 
12436, 9919, 13372, 9526, 8232, 13787, 7398, 10332, 12967, 14288, 
14053, 11620, 11426, 14477, 11464, 9029, 11875, 10873, 8065, 
11233, 13848, 10204, 9535), class = "Date")), datalabel = "", time.stamp = "24 Jan 2015 22:00", .Names = c("id1", 
"date1"), formats = c("%8.0g", "%tdDD_mon_CCYY"), types = c(252L, 
254L), val.labels = c("", ""), var.labels = c("", ""), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"
), version = 12L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your link generates an error: `Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.` You may also want to see if you can re-write your question a bit to be a little more clear, give specific column names and show snippets of the data, etc.

Comment: Perhaps a new reduced ID as the match variable in the larger dataset calculated as `ID - cumsum(tag==1)` .... actual code will require an example.

Comment: @Madiba Thank you for the edits to the post, I will have a look at it. The one other thing that would be very helpful is for you to show us what the results should look like. Do you simply want a resulting dataframe containing all records?

Comment: @Hack-R, yes I want a data set that contains all records.

Comment: @Madiba Great. I think I have the solution for you. Please have a look below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
data <- sqldf("select a.*, b.* from data1 a left join data2 b on a.date = b.date1")
```

or possibly:

```
data <- sqldf("select a.id, a.date from data1 a join data2 b on a.date = b.date1")
```

Comment: thanks for that. However what I really want is a data set that should retain the ID number of the original data set(data1). As an example in a new data ID 428 should correspond to date 19 Jan 2004 and not to 27 Feb 1997.

Comment: @Madiba sorry I misunderstood. Give this a try, though it's just a quick guess. If either of these are right (or wrong) let me know and I'll edit the solution accordingly.

Comment: thanks, the code works perfectly. It is also extremely fast on my larger data set.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could read from your comments on other posts you want to select those rows from data1 that have a tag of 0. This can be achieved using

```
data2 <- data1[data1$tag == 0,]
```